# I have a frame I want to identify.the serial number is GE481578

Tags: identify-this-bike, giant, hardtail

[image]

It's a gray mountain bike frame that says Giant on it and the serial number is GE481578.

Comment: Built sometime between the late 1990's (Disc brake) and 2010ish (Straight steerer tube). By the shape of the seat stays I would guess early in that period. Wild guess is its a Giant :).

Comment: Clearer photos of the driveside dropouts, crank and the paintjob in better light would be a lot of help. There doesn't seem to be a any kind of lookup or database from serial numbers to model+year.

Comment: So - what did you end up doing with this frame, and the information from this question ?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through a few models for various years at http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/Bikes.aspx?year=2004&Brand=Giant

The chainstays on yours don't get narrower towards the rear, suggesting lower-end, but it's not a Boulder, because I can't find a Boulder with a downtube gusset. Disc-only points towards late 2000s mid-range.

Giant's graphics switched from outlined text to block text for the 2007 model year. Many models also switched from downtube gussets to hydroformed downtubes in 2007.

I don't think this is the original paintjob, as I can't find a model with both block text and a downtube gusset. Also, black branding on such a dark colourway doesn't seem like a catalogue option.

My best guess is circa 2006 Rainier, Yukon or Rincon. Extremely unlikely to be an XTC, since those have XTC instead of Giant on the downtube.

Answer (score 1):

Got one like it says xtc on frame after the Giant name. Come as far as it might be an SE model. Frame does match Giants Uk catalogue from Ca 2005 to ca "2008 maybe even newer.